# How to fix Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a layout in which I have a `recyclerView` which include
Two tabs(CustomView) and based on the tab selection I want to update the UI under those tabs. But as the title said, when I am trying to notifyData the app is crashing.

I have check similar posts and I have try the suggestions:
A) To use the `runOnUiThread` to call the `notifyDataSetChange`
B) To use `Handler` and again call the `notifyDataSetChange()`

Also, I have try to use `notifyItemChanged(position)` but again app is crashing.

Comment: please share your logCat completely

Comment: @Alireza Bideli
I have edit my post

Comment: your question need edit more your question has a long title

Answer (score -2):

Guys i found the solution for my problem. So, I'm posting it here if someone need it in the future. The solution was to use an Async Task and do the changes to the list and then notify the adapter!